# Passing value to result with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms-authentication

I have a simple form:

```
<form id="radio_form">
  <fieldset>
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="1" />Red</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="2" />Yellow</label><br />    
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="3" />Blue</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="4" />Purple</label><br />
  </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="6" />12</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="7" />11</label><br />    
    <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="8" />10</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="time" value="9" />9</label><br />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm trying to pass both selected values as a sum to the .result unfortunately .result is showing only values from first input[color]. How can i grab results from both: input[color] and input[time]?

This is my function:

```
$(function(){
    var value = $('input:radio:checked').val();

    $('.result').html(value)


});
```

Many thanks for help in advance.

Dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most of jQuery's getter overloads, `val()` returns only the first item's value.  You could use *map()* and join the resulting array:

```
$(function() {
    var value = $('input:radio:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(" ");  // You could join with a comma if you like

    $('.result').text(value);  // Use text() unless you're adding HTML
});
```

---

Ahh, it appears you're after a running total.  In that case, you'll need *each()* instead:

```
$(function() {
    var value = 0;

    $('input:radio:checked').each(function() {
        value += +this.value;
    });

    $('.result').text(value);  // Use text() unless you're adding HTML
});
```

`+this.value` in the code above coerces the value to a number.

Comment: That works great, the only problem is that I didn't specify that i want a sum of those values as a result. Sorry. how can I so that?

Comment: @Dom: I updated my answer to give you a solution for that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(".result").html(""); // clear result
    $("input:radio:checked").each(function() {
        $(".result").append($(this).val()); // append value of each matched selector
    });
});
```